# Multi and compound secondary index with two numbers in RethinkDB

Tags: database, rethinkdb, nosql

I have documents in an otherwise empty RethinkDB table called `numbers` below containing nested objects. I create a secondary index, a compound and a multi index, on a pair of numbers inside the inner object. Compound because I want to use 2-element arrays as secondary indexes, and multi because the same 2-pair might correspond to multiple documents.

Here, I create that secondary index and insert some documents in the Data Explorer browser view:

```js
r.db('test')
    .table('numbers')
    .indexCreate('idx', [ r.row('group')('a'), r.row('group')('b') ],
                 {multi : true});
r.db('test').table('numbers').insert([
  {name : 'Foo', group : {a : 2, b : 3}},
  {name : 'Bar', group : {a : 2, b : 9}},
  {name : 'Baz', group : {a : 2, b : 3}},
  {name : 'Qwer', group : {a : 4, b : 4}}
]);
```

Now I go to run a query using `between`. For this example, I expect to see three documents returned, but instead *I get no documents back*:

```js
r.db('test').table('numbers').between([ 2, 0 ], [ 3, 5 ], {index : 'idx'});
//  No results returned.
```

Confused, I tested this secondary index with just scalar lookups (so pretending `idx` isn't a compound index): that returns documents!

```js
r.db('test').table('numbers').between(2, 3, {index : 'idx'})
//  3 rows returned: Foo, Bar, Baz
```

What? Why would treating the `idx` secondary array as a scalar index (rather than arrays) and return three documents? What happened to my compound index?

Setting `rightBound` to `closed` doesn't seem to do anything. Also, building the index key using a function, i.e., passing `function(obj) {return [obj('group')('a'), obj('group')('b')];}` to `indexCreate` didn't make a diference.

I've tested another compound multi-index whose keys are [string, number, number], and `between` works great for that multi case: it finds documents. Why won't the two-number multi case work here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the main problem here is that you don't need a multi index.

### Understanding Multi Indexes

> multi because the same 2-pair might correspond to multiple documents

With any secondary index, the index presumes that the value of that property (in this case, the pair of values) corresponds to multiple documents. In RethinkDB, because it's a distributed database, you can only guarantee that a value will be unique for the primary index.

Multi indexes are intended for an array of values for which you want one of those values. Tags are an example of this:

```
{
    "title": "...",
    "content": "...",
    "tags": [ <tag1>, <tag2>, ... ]
}

// Create the multi index based on the field tags
r.table("posts").indexCreate("tags", { multi: true })

// Your query
r.table("posts").getAll(<tag1>, { index: "tags" })
```

### Your Query

Because of this, your can just create the same compound index without it being a multi index.

```
r.db('test')
 .table('numbers')
 .indexCreate('idx', [ r.row('group')('a'), r.row('group')('b') ]);
```

Then your query would return as expected:

```
r.db('test').table('numbers').between([ 2, 0 ], [ 3, 5 ], {index : 'idx'});
```

Returns:

```
{
  "group": {
    "a": 2 ,
    "b": 3
  } ,
  "id":  "f711dae4-7e91-4864-9977-956221a10a08" ,
  "name":  "Foo"
}, {
  "group": {
    "a": 2 ,
    "b": 3
  } ,
  "id":  "29732f5f-a6e6-45e6-aaaf-fd2c9d1bb3fe" ,
  "name":  "Baz"
}, {
  "group": {
    "a": 2 ,
    "b": 9
  } ,
  "id":  "1881eafb-4349-43c8-9fb2-d453720b09a6" ,
  "name":  "Bar"
}
```

Comment: Omg, I can't believe I forgot the purpose of multi indexes, and that they're for allowing the same document to be indexed by multiple keys, *not* that they're for the same key to index multiple documents. Sorry to make you type up such a detailed answer! Many thanks !

Comment: No worries. If that was a bit confusing to you, it's probably confusing for whoever googles this in a couple of days!